# getting error "fatal: Could not read from remote repository" when attempting to deploy a react app to github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

I am working on a react app that i would like to publish to github pages. Before I attempted to deploy this app, i was able to clone, push and do anything in regards to git/github with no problems. But now i am running into

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

when i run
`npm run deploy`

I have cleaned up and reinput my SSH key twice now, I am able to push to the remote repo, I am able to pull from it, I am even able to clone it again. All without any problem, remote origin is correct, pretty much anything I can think of is correct.

images of anything regarding deployment:

package.json:

[image: package.json]

package-lock.json:

[image: package-lock.json]

repo ghpages settings:

[image: repo ghpages settings]

I have tried every solution for both github pages deployment and SSH key problems I can find on stack overflow or even the internet.
At one point I some how did get it to deploy and work. but ran into some other problems after (just simple layout bugs), tried to fix and it broke with the same Permission denied error. I even completely made a new repo, added in a version of my react app before deployment and went through deployment steps from start in new repo, and still ran into the same problems.

Comment: Please put text version of your code and not images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

Hey man I had the same issue, couldn't figure it out either. However there is just a simple workaround, and just wanted to post it in case there are more struggling in the future. First of all I want to state that the remote connection is proper, so I suppose the error is somewhat of a conflict of the OS and gh-pages ( since I just freshly installed Ubuntu, err could be as small as a pkg is missing). Eitherway, when running the
`npm run deploy`
command you'll see that the build is properly being made, and it only throws the err when the script is attempting to push it:

> sudo npm run deploy
> projectname@1 predeploy
> npm run build
> projectname@1 build
> react-scripts build
> Creating an optimized production build...
> Compiled successfully.`

The build made is just in the hidden .build folder in the same parent folder as your master, so just copy this over to a temp place for a second (e.g. desktop), and switch to the gh-pages branch.
`git checkout gh-pages`
Now in your finder / folder / files switch out the files in front of you with the .build folder we copied a second ago and push the repo as normal.
`git add . git commit "Updates" git push origin gh-pages`

For some reason, later on ( like 10m) the error fixed itself and now it doesn't throw this anymore when attempting the command. Only pkg installed in that ten minutes was a removal and install of react-dom, but I have no idea how that would have to do anything with this err.